# How to change output to contain count number in middle of phrase

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wanting to have output containing a count number, but have that count number in the middle of the output phase.

ex:

```
select COUNT(*) " " from product LEFT OUTER JOIN orderdetail ON product.productID=orderdetail.productID where orderid is null;
```

And it returns this output:

[image]

But I want to make it return this output:

[image]

I've been searching for hours on how to do this, and can't figure out a way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does your table structure look like? And where do you want to display the *result*? Typically this would be done server-side on a website, simply storing the value 228 in the database... Like with PHP (for example): `echo "We have " . $number . " products that have never been sold"`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge https://i.imgur.com/Om5jDmX.png and would like to display the result (the number from count) in the middle of the phrase.

Comment: Yes but *why*? Where are you *outputting* the data? To a spreadsheet? To a webpage? There's not usually a need to store the supporting text in a database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT()` AND `CAST()` on `COUNT()` to do this, like this :

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT("We have ", CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR) , " products that have never been sold")
FROM 
    product 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderdetail ON product.productID=orderdetail.productID 
WHERE 
    orderid is null;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works and now i understand what i was messing up on.

Comment: Remember, this would add more steps to do on PHP, for instance, if you want to use that count(*) to use it as variable somewhere else inside your PHP, you would have to trim the returned value to extract the number and then convert it to int ...etc. So, if you see that COUNT(*) would be used somewhere else, I suggest you to just call COUNT(*) and store it inside a variable then use echo to display it within strings.  better than duplicate the query with COUNT(*) only just for that.

Answer (score 0):

In postgres you can use || for concatenation:

```
SELECT 
  'There  are ' ||  COUNT(*)  || ' products that have never been sold')
FROM 
product 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orderdetail ON product.productID=orderdetail.productID 
WHERE  
orderid is null;
```